# JS .hover visibility doesn't work (ASP.NET, VS2013, web forms)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I currently am learning to make ASP.NET app by using VS2013, following the step by step learning from these video series:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUx2Bdx68f4

The video is shown using VS2010

In its masterpage, it uses the following java script to display the sub-menu box when the mouse is hovering over a tab item:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function mainmenu() {
      $("#nav ul").css({ display: "none" }); //Opera fix
      $("#nav li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "visible", display: "none" }).show(400);
      }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
      mainmenu();
    });
  </script>
```

The display is like the following, a sub-menu box is displayed when the mouse is hovering over the "Management" tab item. Example below is showing how it is when I am in the `~/Pages/About` page:

[image]

So far it has no problem, but when I started to create webforms in the sub-folder in my "Pages" folder of the solution called "Account" folder (shown in the image below):

[image]

Then the mouse-hovering to show the sub-menu box is no longer working, but only on the pages in my "Account" subfolder. Example below is when I am in my `~/Pages/Account/Login` page:

[image]

I use the same masterpage for both the `~/Pages/About` and `~/Pages/Account/Login` pages, and in the video (using VS2010), it works fine. But it doesn't work in my app. Anyone can kindly explain why it is so?

Comment: There's an issue in your script path. Change your `src` to `~/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js`

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal I tried it and it got worse. Now I cannot see the sub-menu both in my About page and my Account/Login page :(

Comment: OK, revert back to what you have done before and then open the same page `Login` one. In developer console just check if there's any jquery error.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal I revert back to my earlier version, but I am not sure how to check error from "developer console"(?). Mind to share how?

Comment: If you are using chrome, Firefox or IE F12 will open inspect element window and there you can find console tab. Here all javascript events and error can be tracked, there could be a possibility of $(...) is undefined or $(...).hover is not a function any of these two might be causing this problem.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal Thanks! This is the first time I know there is such developer console! Here is the error: Login.aspx:10 GET http://localhost:64631/Pages/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js 
Login.aspx:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: There are two errors. What do they mean?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal by using the developer console which you mention, I notice that when I open other page, the reference to jquery is to localhost:64631/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js while for the Login page, it is to localhost:64631/Pages/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js . How to make the reference in the masterpage is to localhost:64631/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js absolutely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97953/discussion-between-suprabhat-biswal-and-ian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. Suprabhat Biswal, I get this answer from him (please refer to the chat).

The problem was because in my javascript in the masterpage, I put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=GetBaseURL%>/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

the first one makes the jquery executed always relative to the path of my current page. In my case, that makes the jquery referred when opening `Login` page to be in the `localhost:64631/Pages/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js` (wrong) instead of `localhost:64631/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js` (correct)

To solve it, he suggested me to add a key called `BaseURL` in my web.config and to create C# method named `GetBaseURL` which returns they key value to be used in the java script (the second script). Now it works perfectly fine! :)